# Angular2 : How to get query params in matrix notation

Tags: angular

my url is :

```
http://localhost/#/foo;nb=25;page=1
```

in the component linked to this url, I do :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.queryParamSub = this._route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
           console.log(queryParams)
        })
}
```

However, I keep getting an empty object as `queryParams`. I did try with my url as : `http://localhost/#/foo?nb=25&page=1` and it worked fine. Any idea how can I solve this issue if I want to use the matrix notation ?

EDIT this._route is `ActivatedRoute`

EDIT Here is my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: "",
                component: AppComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                      path: "foo",
                      component: HomepageComponent,
                      data: {
                          name: 'home'
                      }
                    }
                ]
            }]
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The component in which I try to get the query param is `HomepageComponent`

Answer (score 2):

Query parameters on the root route are serialized as query parameters `?xxx=yyy`, query parameters on child routes are serialized as matrix parameters `;xxx=yyy`.

So what you need to do is to add the parameters to a child route segment to get them in matrix notation.

Comment: Sorry mate but I am afraid I don't see what you mean by "add them to a child route segment" ...

Comment: If you have a route `{ path: 'root', children: [{ path: 'child', component: Child}]}` and `this.router.navigate(['/root', {nb:25}, 'child', {page:1}])` you should get `http://localhost/#/root/child;page=1?nb=25` (at the end of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters)

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misinterpreted your question a bit. In addition to my answer which explains when matrix parameters are used, you need to apply the `_route.queryParams.subscribe()` at the right component, the one that was added by the route where the matrix parameters belong to. I don't know if the URL you posed is actually valid. Was this URL created from Angular by the router or did you invent it?

Comment: Can you please provide the routes configuration you're using?

Comment: Done, it seems that using this._route.params instead of this._route.queryParams is doing something.

Comment: Seems I am subject to some confusion here myself. I assumed optional route parameters **are** queryParameters, but it seems they are something different. This is also why they are passed within the array `['/root', {...}]` and not in `routingExtras` that also allows to pass `queryParameters` but only in addition to the entire route not to segments.